# Best way to SELECT multiple fields in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tables and Fields

```
#define TABLE_HOUSE             "house_players" 
#define FIELD_HOUSE_ID          "house_id"
#define FIELD_HOUSE_INTERIOR    "house_interiorID"                      
#define FIELD_HOUSE_OWNERID     "house_ownerID"           
#define FIELD_HOUSE_DESCRIPTION "house_description"            
#define FIELD_HOUSE_PRICE       "house_price"                    
#define FIELD_HOUSE_CASH_STORED "house_cashStored"
#define FIELD_HOUSE_ENT_X       "house_entX"             
#define FIELD_HOUSE_ENT_Y       "house_entY"             
#define FIELD_HOUSE_ENT_Z       "house_entZ"             
#define FIELD_HOUSE_ENT_A       "house_entA"  
#define FIELD_HOUSE_VWID        "house_vwID"   

#define TABLE_HOUSEINT          "house_interiors"
#define FIELD_HOUSE_LEVEL       "house_intLevel"
#define FIELD_HOUSE_INFO        "house_intInfo"           
#define FIELD_HOUSE_EXT_X       "house_intX"             
#define FIELD_HOUSE_EXT_Y       "house_intY"             
#define FIELD_HOUSE_EXT_Z       "house_intZ"             
#define FIELD_HOUSE_EXT_A       "house_intA"                      
#define FIELD_HOUSE_INTID       "house_intID"
```

Query

```
SELECT *, IFNULL(h."FIELD_HOUSE_OWNERID", -1) AS ownerid 
    FROM "TABLE_HOUSE" AS h INNER JOIN "TABLE_HOUSEINT" AS hi 
    ON h."FIELD_HOUSE_INTERIOR" = hi."FIELD_HOUSE_LEVEL"
```

This is my current query

Well my question is, I have seen in many articles that using **SELECT *** is bad coding practice because it could introduce many gateway to attacks. So I am wondering what's the quickest way to fetch all the data from many fields without using SELECT * - I know I could select each field one by one but that's long! Wondering if there is other solutions in doing so.

Thanks!
Patrick

Comment: There is no syntax synonym for select *,  and if there was it would just be a different way to the same problem. Just list out the columns you need.

Comment: Well in this case, I pretty much need every column because I am loading everything on initialisation. I list out all the columns I need for everything but the only time I use SELECT * is when I need all the column. Well 'ALL' is a hyperbole because I am pretty much including fields such as 'house_info' , 'house_interiorID', 'house_id' which is no use to me on that query.

Comment: if you need all the columns, use SELECT * it will be far more readable than listing all the columns that are in the table anyway

Comment: i guess one option is to retreive the column names dynamically instead of "hardcoded", with an extra query. Would that work for you? And what the heck is an sql gateway attack?

Comment: How would I manage to do that? I just mean like a open gate for SQL injections and other attacks.

Comment: "Select *" being "readable"  ... mmmm. So something like "array[6]" (with no direct trace to the dbms column that populates it)  is considered "readable"? @SEarle1986

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is typing all the columns out by hand, you can use

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME,",")  
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME = "TABLE_HOUSE"
```

and then copy the results to the clipboard.

Use `SELECT *` when you really mean `SELECT *`, but avoid it in views.

Comment: Doing the query above you posted just returned 11 0's for me.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't notice the MySQL tag. It does string concatenation differently. I have edited the result - check out the new version.

Comment: I guess I just learned something new but I guess that would require more than 1 statement, so in this case what would be the best option?

Comment: what would be the best option to do what exactly? If you want to get the `SELECT` column list for both tables, you could just modify the code by using `CONCAT(TABLE_NAME, ".", COLUMN_NAME, ",")` and then putting the two table names in the `WHERE` clause: `WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ("TABLE_HOUSE", "TABLE_HOUSEINT")`

Comment: The code posted above. It's joined differently. I see that there's no need of using 'INNER JOIN'

Comment: Your comments suggest you don't really understand what I have done. I haven't rewritten the entire SQL statement for you, I have just demonstrated a way of list all the columns in the first part of the SQL statement - the `SELECT` clause (before the `FROM`.

Comment: I have understood your comments and, the statement you've done was fetching all the columns from a table and concatenate it. My point was, doing your statement just complicates the query even more because the field_name has been changed due to the concatenation.

Comment: Not it hasn't. You were looking for a way to save typing if I understood your request. This just returns Table1.Column1, Table1.Column2, ... Table1.ColumnN, Table2.Column1, Table2.Column...2, ..., Table2.ColumnN

Comment: Oh I see! I got confused, how would I properly write my query doing this method?